# Add two lines on graph using abline in R

Tags: r

I have two variables:

```
x=c(rnorm(10, 5, 1))
y=c(rnorm(10, 5, 1))
```

I want to plot a vertical line at the corresponding x value of the maximum y. I tried abline(v=max(y)) but that did not bring the line up. I am able to get a horizontal line for that max(y) but no vertical line for the corresponding x. I want two line on the point, essentially.

```
plot(x, y)
abline(h=max(y), lty=2, col='red)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `which.max` to find the `x` value that corresponds to the largest `y` value.

```
plot(x, y)
abline(h=max(y), lty=2, col='red')
abline(v=x[which.max(y)], lty=2, col='red')
```

Comment: You can pass h & v in at the same time too - `abline(h=max(y), v=x[which.max(y)], lty=2, col='red')`

Comment: Works like a charm!!